# How to deploy to a new directory structure with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

Is it possible to create a new directory structure when deploying with setuptools?
In my setup.py file, which mirrors my current structure I have

```
  package_dir      = {"": "."},
  packages         = ["",],
  package_data     = {"": ["ItemA/*.py",
                           "ItemB/*.py",
                           "ItemC/*.py",
                           "Master.foo",
                           ] },
```

I cannot change the original structure, but I want to deploy to add two levels of folders before deploying everything.

```
./
 Folder1/Folder2/
                /ItemA/ *.py
                /ItemB/ *.py
                /ItemC/ *.py
                Master.foo
```

Comment: It may be possible with `data_files` https://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to want explicit files It does make the directories like I want, but it wont search for "*.py". I'd have to name all files.

Comment: This almost does it, but it loses the "itemA, itemB" directory each .py lives in.  data_files = [("Folder1/Folder2", glob.glob(" +/+.py"))]  + = star. star isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the data_files as suggested by @pacholik to do what I want. I get the files in the package twice, but thats ok for what I'm trying to do.

Before my setup call, I do this:

```
stuff = []
for f in glob.glob("*/*.py"):
    stuff.append((os.path.join("Folder1/Folder2", os.path.dirname(f)), [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f),os.path.basename(f))] ))
stuff.append( ('esri/toolboxes', ["Master.foo"]))
```

Then just assign  `data_files  = stuff,`

stuff =

```
[('Folder1/Folder2\\ItemA', ['ItemA\\x.py']), ('Folder1/Folder2\\ItemB', ['ItemB\\y.py']), ('Folder1/Folder2\\ItemC', ['ItemC\\z.py']), ('Folder1/Folder2', ['Master.foo'])]
```